# Probability Question on Urns and numbered balls

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

An urn contains $10$ balls numbered $1$ to $10$.  A set of  $3$ balls is drawn from the urn. Let  $X$ record the largest number showing.

Compute $P(X=7)$.

I have to do this on excel. I'm assuming I have to use the combin() function, but I don't understand if this type of question is different from this question:

An urn contains $30$ red balls and 70 white balls.  A set of 10 balls is drawn from the urn without replacement. Let $X$ count the number of red balls drawn from the urn. Find $P(x=4)$ where I use the hypgeom() function.

Comment: If $X = 7$, then one of the $3$ balls drawn shows $7$, and the other two show two smaller numbers. What is the probability that the first ball shows $7$, and the second and third show smaller numbers? Multiply this probability by the number of permutations of three distinct numbers, that is $3!$. That gives $P(X = 7)$.

Comment: so in excel, would you do the binom.dist() where you would input this:

Comment: No idea about that, sorry.

Comment: @M.Vinay Well okay so ignoring excel. so the first part is (1/10) because the probability of the first ball showing up to be 7 is 1/10 and then you multiply by 6/9 since there is one less ball and there are 6 balls that will be less than 7 then the next is multiplying by 5/8?.Then multiply the whole thing by 3?

Comment: Multiply by the factorial, $3!$, not $3$. $3! = 6$. This is assuming you're drawing the balls without replacement.

Comment: What if the balls were drawn with replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without replacement:

There are $\dbinom{10}{3}$ ways to pick the $3$ balls out of $10$.

There are $\dbinom{6}{2}$ ways to do this under condition $X=7$.

So: $$P\left(X=7\right)=\binom{6}{2}\binom{10}{3}^{-1}$$

I suspect that 'combin($n,k$)' gives you $\dbinom{n}{k}$ in excel.